# Adding dropdown sku list to my form - Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray

Tags: model, forms, module

I am working on a custom module and this is one of my form:

[image]

At the moment, I am using a text input for "Magento SKU". The form is constructed like this:

*Company_Integration_Block_Adminhtml_Manageskumappings_Edit_Tab_Form*

```
$fieldset->addField('magento_sku', 'text', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Magento SKU'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'magento_sku'
));

$fieldset->addField('sage_sku', 'text', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Sage SKU'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'sage_sku'
));

$fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Status'),
    'name' => 'status',
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Enabled')
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 2,
            'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Disabled')
        )
    )
));
```

I want to turn this field `magento_sku` into a drop down list (from existing sku in magento).

I know I can do this manually by doing this:

```
$fieldset->addField('magento_sku', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('form')->__('Magento SKU'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'title',
    'value'     => '1',
    'values'    => array(
        '-1'    => 'Please Select..',
        'SKU1'  => 'SKU1',
        'SKU2'  => 'SKU3',
        'SKU3'  => 'SKU3'
    )
));
```

How can I automate this, so that this field is auto-populated from an external source (model? helper?) within my module?

---

This is my module config: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ATy2NnEL

This is what I tried so far:

```
$fieldset->addField('magento_sku', 'select', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Magento SKU'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'magento_sku',
    'values' => Mage::getSingleton('manageskumappings/skus')->toOptionArray()
));
```

My model was here: *app\code\local\Company\Integration\Model\Skus.php* with the following:

```
class Company_Integration_Model_Skus extends Varien_Object
{
    static public function getOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            '-1'    => 'Please Select..',
            'SKU1'  => 'SKU1',
            'SKU2'  => 'SKU3',
            'SKU3'  => 'SKU3'
        );
    }
}
```

When I did this, I get the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object` similar to my other question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222513/magento-call-to-a-member-function-getoptionarray-on-a-non-object

Comment: Why the down vote, is this not a valid question?

Comment: It should be a requirement that people explain why they downvote. That's SO for ya. I found your question helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this piece of code will help you.

```
$products = array();
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc');
$i = 1;
$items = $productCollection->getData();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $products[$i]['value'] = $item['sku'];
    $products[$i]['label'] = $item['sku'];
    $i++;
}

$fieldset->addField('magento_sku', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Product SKU'),
    'name'      => 'magento_sku',
    'values'    => $products,
    'required'  => true
));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Mage::getSingleton('manageskumappings/skus')->toOptionArray()
```

with:

```
Mage::getSingleton('skumappings/skus')->toOptionArray()
```

as according to your config file the correct alias of your module is `skumappings`.

Also I don't see any reason in declaring `getOptionArray` method as `static`.

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting a different error: `Invalid method Company_Integration_Model_Skus::toOptionArray(Array())`

Comment: Why don't you pull SKUs inside of your `Company_Integration_Block_Adminhtml_Manageskumappings_Edit_Tab_Form` class?

Comment: That's what I am having to do now. I thought it would be neater/easier to manage if it was a model file on it's own.

Comment: have you removed `static` from `toOptionArray` method?